# Knex postgres connection working even with wrong password

Tags: postgresql, api, knex.js

I'm pretty new to working with knex/postgres, I'm setting up a basic JWT auth server and everything seems to work perfectly...Even when I enter the wrong password for my postgres user. I've setup a postgres server with a new database and user for managing operations. This user has a set password (confirmed on `pg_shadow`), however, in my knex connection settings if I set the wrong password for the user all queries go through without issue. Setting the wrong user raises an not-found-user exception and setting neither user nor password works fine too (though in this case I'm assuming knex is using my system default user?)

Any help or information is much appreciated as I'm still learning how Knex works properly.

Thanks everyone

Config:

```js
    client: "pg",
    connection: {
      database: "database_name",
      user: "right_user",
      password: "wrong_password",
      filename: "./db/connection.ts",
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: "./db/migrations",
    },
    seeds: {
      directory: "./db/seeds",
    }
```

Comment: The auth method is controlled by pg_hba.  Yours is apparently set to a non-password based method.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: Ahh I see, I'll take a look at that! Thanks a lot :)